# How do I write an SQL Query to Update All Rows That Meet a Criteria And Then Add Another Character Inline

Tags: sql, db2

I have written a query that will search column1 in my Table A when the length of the entry is < 8 characters.  The query is generally this:

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2
FROM SCHEMA.A as A
WHERE length(A.Column1) < '8';
```

This gets me all the results I expect.  Now what I want to do is for every one of these results I want add a '-' character after the 4th character in every result.  For example, if my original query produced a row that had a column1 of 1234567, I would want it be updated to be 1234-567. This would be true for all returned rows.  I can do this using java code but I was hoping to write an sql script instead as it's faster and won't be throw away.  I have looked at various db2 Update syntax examples but none show exactly what I am looking for. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`INSERT()` function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000813.html):

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.A
    SET Column1 = INSERT(Column1, 5, 0, '-')
    WHERE length(A.Column1) < 8;
```

Try this using a `SELECT` before doing the update.

Also, `length()` returns a number.  The comparison value should be a number, not a string.

Comment: Hi Gordon, appreciate the tip. That works for me. Just for posterity, here is the final query that worked since it still took time to get the SELECT and Update to work together:
SELECT Column1
FROM FINAL TABLE (UPDATE SCHEMA.A SET Column1 = INSERT(Column1, 5, 0, '-') WHERE length(Column1) < 8 );

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you dont want add '-' character if you column lenght are < 4
Example : 123 you dont want 123-,  and 1234 you dont want 1234- then you must rectify your where condition like it:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA.A
SET Column1 = left(Column1, 4) || '-' || substr(Column1, 5)
WHERE length(Column1) between 4 and 7;
```

Comment: In this case it won't matter, but if it did I would agree w/ you that it's worth considering. Thanks for the ideas!